# Apex Final Property Behaves Like a Member Variable

Tags: apex, execute-anonymous, setter, properties

Assume we have a simple class:

```cs
public with sharing class SomeClass {

    public String property {
        get;
        set;
    } {
        property = 'Default Property Value';
    }

    public final String finalProperty {
        get;
        set { finalProperty = value; }
    } {
        finalProperty = 'Default Final Property Value';
    }

    public final String finalAutoProperty {
        get;
        set;
    } {
        finalAutoProperty = 'Default Final AutoProperty Value';
    }

}
```

**Anonymous Execution**

```cs
SomeClass instance = new SomeClass();
instance.property = 'New Property Value';
instance.finalProperty = 'New Final Property Value'; // Works
instance.finalAutoProperty = 'New Final AutoProperty Value'; // Fails with
```

> System.FinalException: Final variable has already been initialized
> `Class.SomeClass.__sfdc_finalAutoProperty`

However, as @sfdcfox сorrectly noticed, neither
`instance.finalProperty = 'New Final Property Value';` nor `instance.finalAutoProperty = 'New Final AutoProperty Value';` reassignments
couldn't be compiled within another method giving:

> Final members can only be assigned in their declaration, init blocks, or constructors

This behavior gives me questions because:

1. [**final** keyword](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_final.htm) ApexDocs doesn't mention that the `final` keyword affects the behavior of properties and the [Apex Properties](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm) page doesn't mention the `final` keyword. But the `final` keyword **does affect** apex properties.
2. Is it undocumented expected behavior or a new bug?
3. Why it is possible to reassign the property value within anonymous execution via default setter, but not via auto-generated setter?

Comment: Possibly you've done something "wrong." I tested your second code block, and I get the expected error. Can you please provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) that compiles?

Comment: Well, then, possibly I've done something wrong. I can't reproduce the behavior you describe. The final code block, how are you calling it? When I try to write a method that duplicates this, it works. Here's my example, for reference. https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/e2f3e54130eb97d754b586cc8960f772

Comment: My bad. Actually, It was possible to reassign a final property value via its explicit setter from anonymous execution. So either I will rewrite the question, or delete it. Sorry for the wasted time.

Comment: Exec Anon is a bit "weird" sometimes, which might explain things. If you still want me to look, I'd be happy to, just include the exec anon code.

Comment: @sfdcfox I've Updated the question, and I hope it still makes some sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *don't* provide a property for the final default getter setter property, it *also* runs just fine instead of "*System.FinalException: Final variable has already been initialized*".

Generally speaking, Exec Anon is weird, because it's basically a hack to the existing runtime. It doesn't allow classes that are nested, nor can you have static variables in those classes, etc, as if the entire code was wrapped in a class, but you can also intersperse methods and classes with executable code, as if it were not.

Also, you may want to read more about [Execute Anonymous](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_anonymous_block.htm). It has a wide range of unusual rules that differ from normal gameplay. For example:

> Unlike classes and triggers, anonymous blocks execute as the current user and can fail to compile if the code violates the user's object- and field-level permissions.

This is apparently one of those holes in the system. This behavior is clearly showing that the Exec Anon script is called as if it were executing in a constructor context, even though it allows DMLs (which are normally not allowed in a constructor or getter).

I can't say for certain if this is a bug, but this is definitely an Exec Anon exception to the normal rules for execution. If you're a prolific user of Exec Anon, you may very well find many strange and wonderful quirks hidden within.

However, as far as normal, compiled Apex code goes, you must always follow the prescribed directions as written in the documentation, or you will likely come across compilation errors, weird runtime behavior, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is clear now that anonymous execution is full of weirdness. Apart from it, [**final** keyword](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_final.htm)  page doesn't mention properties at all (only does mention member variables). Also, [**Apex Properties**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm) page doesn't mention the `final` keyword.